# How to apply transform in UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have applied below transform to UIView's layer like this:

```
 CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
 rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -850;
 rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, M_PI_4*1.1,0.0f, 1.2f, 0.0f);
 self.centerView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

But not so much success i just wanted to apply transform like shown below image[image]

Any help would so much appreciated. Thanks for reading my Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this could be helpful

```
CATransform3D t1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
t1.m34 = 1.0/-850;
t1 = CATransform3DScale(t1, 0.95, 0.95, 1);
t1 = CATransform3DRotate(t1, 15.0f*M_PI_4/180.0f, 0, 1.2, 0);

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t1];
animation.duration = 1;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Comment: i will not be able test code until monday.@thanks for answering