# Transform a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want transform a view along Y axis. My code work fine But they back to its orginal postion after a sec.I am not needed this.

```
CABasicAnimation* animation =[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
animation.fromValue = @(0);
animation.toValue = @( M_PI/4);
animation.repeatCount = 0.0;
animation.duration = 5.0;

[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];

CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
self.view.layer.transform = transform;
```

Comment: Add animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018994/how-to-apply-transform-in-uiview

Answer (score 1):

If you want your view stop at where animation stops,try this

```
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply an animation on a layer you are working with its `presentationLayer` and not its `modelLayer`, you layer snap back to the original value because you still didn't modify the model layer.
To make things works you need to update the model layer too also because keeping the presentation layer with a value and the model with another value can lead to further problems.

```
CABasicAnimation* animation =[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
animation.fromValue = @(0);
animation.toValue = @( M_PI/4);
animation.repeatCount = 0.0;
animation.duration = 5.0;

[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];
self.view.layer.transform = //Apply the transformation
```

Furthermore, before the animation ends, you apply again a transformation that except for its perspective component is the same of the original layer.
If you want to do that at the end of the animation you should set the a delegate for the CABasicAnimation.

For more info check [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html) and [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/11/prevent-caanimation-snap-back/).

Answer (score 0):

To keep you view last state of your animation completed. and does't removed your animation when its completed.

```
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Hope this help you..